# Edge "security certificate is not secure" since bash installation

Tags: windows-10, certificate, microsoft-edge, windows-subsystem-for-linux

### Description

I am running Windows 10 Insider - Build 14316. I managed to reproduce the issue by reverting the update and try it again to see exactly when the problem occurs.

So, I activated [Ubuntu On Windows](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/14/howto-ubuntu-on-windows-2/), and just at the moment I launched the **bash** command inside an administrator prompt (*i.e.* the Linux Subsystem was *effectively* installed), Edge started to warn me about certificates problems.

The message is (see screenshot **#1**) :

> There is a problem connecting securely to this website. The security
>   certificate presented by this website is not secure.

- Only secured websites were concerned but not all ;
- Facebook was concerned for example, **with** "Continue to this website" displayed (which actually does nothing) ;
- [This Microsoft page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/insider/) is ironically concerned, **without** "Continue to this website" showed ;
- Some downloads, *i.e.* the Firefox setup (on Edge!), will fail with the following message which seems related to my primary question (see screenshot **#2**) :

> The signature of this program is corrupt or invalid.

However, other downloads will work as excepted.

Note that other browsers (Chrome, Firefox) will display all websites without any error.

---

### What I've tried so far

- Set correct datetime in Windows (that was already the case). Please note that the **time** command on bash gives incorrect hour (2 hours late) ;
- In Internet Options (*inetcpl.cpl*), uncheck some options relatives to certificate, signature checking and cleared SSL State ;
- From [Microsoft Catalog Update](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/), I updated root certificates. **It solved the problem with Facebook, but not with the Microsoft page linked above.**
- Reset IE settings ;
- Remove Linux subsystem, `lxrun /uninstall /full` ;
- `certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512` ;
- `sfc /scannow`, etc., just in case.

None of these attempts worked.

---

### Screenshots

**#1**[image: Edge message certificate error]

**#2**[image: Edge message download signature]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I hope that I've been clear, don't hesitate to ask for additional information.

Comment: The only reason you would be getting this is if you were being sent the incorrect certificate, or if your machine no longer trusted the certificate authorities, which sign the bulk of the certificates.  Without specific certificate information on the sites that are not working, which cannot be retrieved using Edge, there simply enough information to determine the source of your problem.  Use IE11 to display the certificate information for those websites.  Having a VM, with this version of Windows installed, I personally was unable to reproduce this problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your comment. I am unable to display the certificate information using IE11. There is no option "Continue to this website", so I can't continue and access the certificate. Let me know if there is another option. See this screenshot : http://puu.sh/on2Yo/7a2fbe534d.png

Comment: Research how you view the certificate information in IE11 for a website.  You don't have to continue to the website to view the certificate information you seek.  Please update your question to include the image hosted on `i.stack.imgur.com` instead of `puu.sh` with a preference for it to be in English.  Verify your proxy settings are incorrect, the fact even Firefox is having a problem, indicate a system wide configuration problem.

Comment: @Ramhound All the methods I found ask to click on the error about the certificate or on the padlock, I don't see one of them. I really cannot found a way to see the certificate. Question updated. Sorry if I have been misunderstood, Firefox has no problem, I was talking about downloading Firefox setup (on Edge).